# How to record screen for showing code or design?

Tags: video, code, screen-recorder

I'm looking to be able to make a video/gif like this https://dribbble.com/shots/4920325-Social-share-button
I created some similar design with css. But now I don't how to get a video like that. I tried screen recording but the quality is so bad because I had to restrict the recording window size.
How to get a video of what I made, in reasonable quality?

Answer (score 1):

[OBS](https://obsproject.com/) would be great for recording anything from games to desktop stuff.

Alternatively you can try using the built in [windows game bar](https://www.theverge.com/2020/4/21/21222533/record-screen-pc-windows-laptop-xbox-game-bar-how-to) (Win + G)

also maybe try zooming on the web page (Ctrl + Plus) of what you want to record to possibly get a higher quality

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Comment: Windows Game Bar is built-in and seems pretty capable - to the point I'm wondering if there is something equivalent in Linux